# Find the limit of sequence with respect to a given topology

Tags: general-topology, limits

> Find the limit of sequence $x_{n} = (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ with respect to the topology $$\tau = \{(n,\infty)\times (n, \infty): n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{\emptyset,\mathbb{R^2}\}.$$

**My work**. Let $x$ be a limit.

If $x<0$, every number can be a limit, because in this case neighbourhood of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

If $x > 0$. For example, if $x = (0,0)$, neighbourhood looks like $(0,\infty)\times (0, \infty)$. So, here is not limit for sequence $x_n$?? Or limit equals $(1,1)$??

Comment: that's not a topology

Comment: @mathworker21 so, there is no limit for that sequence?

Comment: @mathworker21 Why do you think that $\tau$ is not a topology?

Comment: @mathworker21 and why its not topology?? I have checked it and I got topology

Comment: @RobertZ $((1,\infty)\times(1,\infty))\cap ((2,\infty)\times(2,\infty)) = (1,2)\times(1,2)$.

Comment: @Aleksandra Note that any limit should be a point $\mathbb{R^2}$. What does it mean that the limit is $1$?

Comment: @mathworker21 actually $((2,\infty)\times(2,\infty))\subset  ((1,\infty)\times(1,\infty))$

Comment: @RobertZ whoops. my brain rots with age

Comment: @RobertZ ah! point (1,1)

Comment: $(0,0)$ is not in $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$, contrary to your claim.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that the sequence $\left((\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\right)_{n\geq 1}$ is eventually contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus ((1,\infty)\times(1,\infty))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's abstract a bit: the topology is just a decreasing sequence of open sets $U_1 \supset U_2 \supset U_3 \supset \ldots $ with empty intersection, and the compulsory $\emptyset, X$ are open too. It's quite easy to check that this always gives a topology.

Now in our case, $U_n = (n,\infty) \times (n, \infty)$ of course and the sequence
has the property:

$$\forall n: x_n \in U_0, x_n \notin U_1$$

Now for any point $p$ not in $U_1$, the only open neighbourhoods it has are (possibly $U_0$) and in $X$, and in both cases, this contains the whole sequence. So $x_n \to p$ for $p \notin U_1$ and if $p \in U_1$, then $U_1$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ such that no tail of the sequence lies in it (it entirely misses the sequence in fact), and so $x_n$ cannot converge to $p$.

So there lots of limits for this sequence : all points $(x,y) \notin (1,\infty) \times (1,\infty)$ i.e. all $(x,y)$ with $x \le 1$ or $y \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The only neighbourhood of $x_n$ for $n>1$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since for any point in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus((1,\infty)\times(1,\infty))$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the only neighbourhood incidentally containing infinitely many points of $\{x_n\}$.  points $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus((1,\infty)\times(1,\infty))$ is set of limit points of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is A limit, but not the only one...

Comment: @RobertZ: Yeah.

Comment: @RobertZ but for example, if we take $n=2$, neighbourhood wouldnt look like $(2,\infty)\times (2,\infty)$?

Comment: @Aleksandra: $\left(\dfrac12,\dfrac12\right)\not\in(2,\infty)\times (2,\infty)$

Comment: @YadatiKiran Ah! I see it now!!